# Construct `std::string` from dynamically allocated char array in an owning way

Tags: c++, string, unique-ptr

I am working with a library which returns a dynamically allocated null-terminated character string

```cpp
const char* dynamically_allocated_string();
```

so I am responsible for calling `delete` on the returned value later. My first instinct is to wrap the value in a `unique_ptr` so that all the memory management is done automatically:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<const char[]> ptr{dynamically_allocated_string()};
```

If I want to make a `std::string` from this, I could call the string constructor as

```cpp
std::string{ptr.get()};
```

However, this makes a copy of the existing character string to construct the `std::string`. Is there a way to both

1. Wrap a dynamically allocated character string with `std::string` such that the underlying array is automatically `delete`d when the string goes out of scope
2. Avoid copying the original character string during `std::string`'s construction

I am aware of `string_view` but it does not take ownership of the original character array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no interface in `std::string` to take ownership of externally allocated buffers, unfortunately.

One option is to provide an oversized `std::string` buffer to the function that fills the buffer (if there is such an interface) and then trim that string to the actual size.

Otherwise, if you'd like to stick with `std::` components and avoid allocating/copying the string your best choice is `std::unique_ptr<const char[]>` (may be with a custom deleter that matches the allocation function) converted into `std::string_view` on demand, as you mention in your question.